# Jenkins Docker pipeline plugin with docker run

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-run

I have a **Jenkins pipeline** with the **Docker Pipeline plugin** installed.

I would like to run a docker container with the plugin using the following command:

```
docker.image("$uri/$name:$tag").run("-it --name myWebApp -v /myData:/mywebapp/data")
```

However, however, Jenkins'log console shows me nothing. I use `-it` to show the log and the process until it is finished, however it seems not to work.

Looking at the official documentation, it seems to use `-d`, in `detached` mode. I have seen that type `withRun` and I have tried the following command:

```
docker.image("$uri/$name:$tag").run("-it --name myWebApp -v /myData:/mywebapp/data") { c-> 
   sh "docker logs ${c.id}"
}
```

However it stops after a few seconds showing this:

```
docker logs 897sdfhdv87sdXX
```

How do I start a docker container normally? By showing the logs and synchronously? It ends in exit 0 type when the container ends successfully

Answer (score 1):

Hi I know this probably is no longer needed, but I believe this is achievable by doing something like:

```
docker.image('mysql:5').withRun('-e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw"') { c ->
    sh "docker logs ${c.id}"
}
```

This example was adapted from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/